# How to perform Hold event in Windows Phonw 8?

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

I'm trying to deal with hold event on  my Windows Phone 8 project.

This is my list's tap event

```
    private void lstData_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        Bus selectedItemData = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Bus;
        if (selectedItemData != null)
        {
            var num = selectedItemData.Number;
            var route = selectedItemData.Route;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/Details.xaml?parameter1=" + num + "&parameter2=" + route), UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

And this is Hold event

```
    private void lstData_Hold(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBoxResult m = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add this bus to favorite list", "Add to Favorite", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if(m==MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            Bus selectedItemData2 = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Bus;
            if (selectedItemData2 != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(selectedItemData2.Route);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that selectedItemData2 in Hold event comes null when I debugged. I can't understand how it is possible that it work for tap event but not for hold event. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that tap and hold events are not triggered simultaneously.
1) Try commenting out Tap event and debug it again. 
2) Try if the sender contains the ListBox in the parameter of hold event

Answer (score 1):

When Hold event fired , the item you holded was not selected.But you can access the item which holded e.OriginalSource in your hold event.